# How do you create a table using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

What I'm trying to do is create a table (7 columns and 5 rows) using only jQuery. The  are the days of the week (eg. Monday, Tuesday, etc.)

This is the HTML version of what I'm trying to create in jQuery:

```
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Sunday</th><th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th><th>Thursday</th><th>Friday</th><th>Saturday</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td><td>4</td><td>4</td><td>4</td><td>4</td><td>4</td><td>4</td>
  </tr>
```

I also need to style the  background-color all one color. Then the rest of the rows are alternating colors. Please help me solve this problem.

This is what I have:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      for(var i=0; i < 5; i++) {



        for(var j=0; j < 7; j++) {
          $("#container").append( "Sunday" + "Monday" + "Tuesday" + "Wednesday" + "Thursday" + "Friday" + "Saturday" + i );
          if (i == 0) {

            $("th").css("background-color", "#ccc");
          } else if {
            $(this).css("background-color", "red");
          }
        }
      }
      $("#container").append('</table>');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So what is the issue you are having?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way...

```js
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    rowCount = 4;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('<table/>'),
        head = $('<thead/>'),
        body = $('<tbody/>'),
        headrow = $('<tr/>');

    $.each(days, function(index, day) {
        headrow.append('<th>' + day + '</th>');
    });
    head.append(headrow);

    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        var bRow = $('<tr/>');
        for (var j = 0; j < days.length; j++) {
            bRow.append('<td>' + (i + 1) + '</td>');
        }
        body.append(bRow);
    }
    table.append(head).append(body).appendTo('body');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

here u can simplify :

```
dayOfTheWeek = ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"];
str = '<table>';
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
{ 
    var s = '';
    t1='<tr>'; 
    t2='</tr>'; 
    for(j=0;j<dayOfTheWeek.length;j++)
    { 
        t3 = i; 
        if (i==0)
        { 
            t1='<th>'; t2='</th>'; t3 = dayOfTheWeek[j]; 
        } 
        s+= '<td>'+t3+'</td>'; 
    }  
    s = t1+s+t2;
    str += s;
}
str+='</table>';

$(str).appendTo($('#container'));
```